# How to change URL according to server in dnn

Tags: url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, webmatrix

I have Create a website in DotnetNuke using WebMetrix  .The Website has been finished and run successfully on my local system .  But when i moved my website to production server then instead of opening the Server URL  it redirecting to my localhost URL.
So i think it requires any host setting or alias setting or URL setting from the Application or DB.Please suggest how can i resolve this issue.Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a Portal Alias to the PortalAliases table, for the production URL. I would also recommend that you remove the testing URL from that table as well in production.